# If dCalendar using measure

Tags: powerbi

I'm fairly new to PowerBi and i'm having some issues with dates.
The code of a new column in dCalendar is this:

```
Auxiliary Line Chart = 
    VAR EndDate = [Day N]

    Return IF(dCalendar[Date] <= EndDate; "TRUE"; "FALSE")
```

Where [Day N] it's in this case the day 10/02/2020.
dCalendar it's a table with dates from 01/01/2019 to 31/12/2021.

For some reason I can't understand, the only day that shows "TRUE" is 04/03/2020.

Edit: [Day N] is a measure and both [Days N] and dCalendar[Date] are Date types
Edit 2: [Day N] uses a column to calculate it that is linked to dCalendar[Date]. Maybe this is what's making all this trouble. But I thought that using VAR locked the value for the entire column

Comment: What is the type of your [Day N] column?

Comment: As Dreekun has mentioned, this maybe because of an issue with the data type. Check the data type for both [Day N] and dCalendar[date] to make sure they are dates..

Comment: [DayN] is a measure

Comment: Even measures have data types. Check in the modelling tab by clicking on both the measure and the column and see if they are date values.

Comment: @CR7SMS, yes, the measure is a date type, I also use this measure to set some dates and it works just ok.

Comment: Is [Auxiliary Line Chart] a calculated column? or is it a measure? 
Also which is the formula of [Day N] measure?